# What's the PEP8 / best practice for Python multiline comments?

Tags: python, pep8

I use a lot the code pattern:

```
1    class myTest():
2        counter = 0      # use this as general counter
3        name_code = ''   # this is the name encoded using the
4                         # standard as defined in ...
5        category = ''    # category of test
```

Line 4 is not PEP8 standard. # should be at position 5 which looks IMHO just ugly:

```
3        name_code = ''   # this is the name encoded using the
4        #                  standard as defined in ...
```

How do you comment such a pattern?
What is best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would document the variables in the class [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), because they are static members of the class. This way your actual code stays more compact, and easier to read and digest:

```
class myTest():
    """Test class which does something.

    Attributes:
        counter (int): Use this as general counter.
        name_code (str): This is the name encoded using the
            standard as defined in this long piece of text.
            Just continue the lines with one level of indentation
            for as long as you want.
        category (str): Category of the test.

    """

    counter = 0
    name_code = ''
    category = ''
```

I've used the [Google style Python docstring](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html) here, because that's just my preferred style for these.

Answer (score -2):

I'd do them as [*docstrings*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), so they're actually available to other tools like Sphinx, and can be used in e.g. generation of documentation:

```
class myTest():
    counter = 0
    """use this as general counter"""

    name_code = ''
    """this is the name encoded using the standard as defined in ..."""

    category = ''
    """category of test"""
```

Docstrings are conventionally multiline strings, so can be extended to multiple lines as required.

For example, [here's](https://github.com/textbook/flash_services/blob/1d8e6e2e083db1bb6aed82ea05f2810f324fb8b3/flash_services/core.py#L71) a class whose attributes I've documented with docstrings, allowing [this](https://flash-services.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flash_services.html#flash_services.core.Service) documentation to be automatically generated from it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe
> I thought they were required to be after ..
What are you exactly referring to?

Comment: @VengaVenga the string literals are required to be after the attribute definitions to count as docstrings.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so it should be:

Comment: So it should be:
        name_code = ''   ''' this is the name encoded using the
                             standard as defined in ... '''
? That shouldn't be. You'd get an 'unexpected indentation' error in PEP8.

Comment: It should be how I've written it in my answer. It's hard to tell from a comment what exactly you've done.